# Using QgsFeatureRendererV2 methods writeSld() and loadSld() in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, export, style, import

I have a vector layer in QGIS and using Python I would like to be able to export the layer styling to a string variable and import styling in a string variable to the layer again (pseudo code):

```
style_string = layer_1.rendererV2().export_style()
layer_2.rendererV2().import_style(style_string))
```

I have found the two methods [`writeSld(...)`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRendererV2.html#ae429cdcf8219b1f8f8c3c02a67871ead) and [`loadSld(...)`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRendererV2.html#abbc3992b09f5580b714c19a25cdd53ca) in the [`QgsFeatureRendererV2`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRendererV2.html) but I cannot find any examples of how to use them together.

The only clue I have found was this [blog post](http://www.webrian.ch/2012/04/native-sld-support-in-qgis.html) which describes how `writeSld(...)` can be used. But when I try to import the XML document back into the renderer using `loadSld(...)` QGIS gives me a *minidump*.

**Question:**
Can anyone give me an example of how this can be done?